# Reset Gmail settings to default

Tags: gmail, account-management

Is it possible to reset Gmail settings to the default settings?

Which will be like the settings you get when opening your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but only manually by looking at reference pictures of fresh account. These tutorials can be used as those references:

- **https://youtu.be/UaX15zFXCRc**
- **https://youtu.be/0D7H4p_luvs**

In other words, Gmail does not have any "reset to default" button so the only way is to track back those settings from various online sources or by creating a new account and checking and using those settings as the reference point.